# Possible to create a blockquote in Apple Notes?

Tags: notes.app

I'm using Apple Notes for lots of things lately (especially after discovering the Safari [note taking workflow described here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/use-apple-notes-research-tool/)). Often I want to indicate a section is a quote, much like I can with Markdown, here in Stack Exchange, in GitHub, Slack, etc.

> Like this

Is there any way to do a blockquote in Apple Notes?

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen such an option. In macOS, the built-in help (`Help > Notes Help`) makes no mention of a block quote feature in the "Write and format notes" section, and a search within Notes help for "quote" did not return any results.

I think your best option is to increase the indentation of the text using `Format > Indentation > Increase` (`⌘]`).

On iOS and iPadOS, there is an option to increase indent under the format (`Aa`) menu.